# Modifying value in Hashtable

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

Hello I come to a problem with modifying certain value in hashtable when two keys are equal.

I define my hashtable,

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> hash = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
```

and my program fills it with some data with `.put()` method.

note: first column represents hex values

```
08 86
AA 10
FF 330
2A 54
E1 60
```

I can check for string duplicates with `if(hash.containsKey(string x)){}`. If I want to insert another data in hashtable, but with the same string `hash.put("AA", 77);` I simply dont know how to add the value in hashtable with my new value together and have hashtable with no duplikate strings. That means to have my final hastable looking likewise

```
08 86
AA 87
FF 330
2A 54
E1 60
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am just curious  to know what is the point of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have an assigment where i have to analyze network packets. I want to know which IP adress sends the most bytes and i started to map them by using hashtable. And if I get 2 identical IP adresses i want to add up their total sent bytes. I keep track of my IP addresses in hex code (first column) and their total bytes (second column). Hashtable might not be the best option but, oh well..

Comment: good question, and please add this explanation to your post so other can understand your goal or may suggest better data structure for you

Answer (score 2):

```
String yourKey = "AA";
int val = 77;
if (hashtable.containsKey(yourKey))
    val += hashtable.get(yourKey));
hashtable.put(yourKey, val);
```

This checks for duplicates and then if there is, add original value to the table

Comment: Thank you sir, it seems that you have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your HashTable to a `HashMap<String, Integer>` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) since the put of HashMap will not add a new key:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replace

Answer (score 0):

You could change your Hashtable to contain an Array or a List of Integers and provide your own put method:

```
Hashtable<String, List<Integer>> hash = new Hashtable<String, List<Integer>>();

public void put(String key, Integer i) {
  if (hash.containsKey(key)) {
    List l = hash.get(key);
    if (l == null) {
      l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      hash.put(key, l);
    }
    if (!l.contains(i)) {
      l.add(i);
    }
  }
}
```